# Proving an algebraic equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to prove this equality:

If $bz + cy = cx + az = ay + bx$ and
 $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2xy - 2xz - 2yz = 0,$ then 
$a \pm b \pm c = 0$

I tried to find x, y, z from the above three equations and substitute them in the fourth but I don’t get anything meaningful.

Comment: Can you show any work towards a solution? This feels like a homework problem. You can probably get more answers by outlining your best effort.

Comment: Set $k=bz+cy$ etc. and apply http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CramersRule.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's wrong.

Try $x=y=z=0$ and $a=b=c=1$.

I tried to understand what you could mean.

Let $cx+az=bx+ay=cy+bz=k,$ where $k\neq0$ and $abc\neq0.$

Thus, $$x=\frac{k(b+c-a)}{2bc},$$
$$y=\frac{k(a+c-b)}{2ac}$$ and
$$z=\frac{k(a+b-c)}{2ab}.$$
Id est,
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\left(\frac{k(b+c-a)}{2bc}\right)^2-2\cdot\frac{k(b+c-a)}{2bc}\cdot\frac{k(a+c-b)}{2ac}\right)=0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4-2a^2b^2)=0$$ or
$$(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)=0,$$ which does not give $a+b+c=0$ again.

Comment: On the other hand, if we demand that there exist a simultaneous solution $(x,y,z)$ all of whose coordinates are non-zero...maybe OP forgot about some hypothesis?

Comment: You’re right I looked at the problem again and saw that I made a mistake transcribing it. Still your answer gives enough information to solve the problem so thank you and I am sorry about the confusion.