# Algebra precalculus problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

I need to solve this problem and I don’t know how.

If $y^2 + z^2 + yz = a^2$

$z^2 + x^2 + zx = b^2$

$x^2 + y^2 + xy = c^2$

$yz + zx + xy = 0,$ then

$a \pm b \pm c = 0$

I can see that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 2(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$ which I suppose can be useful but then I don’t know what to do next. Can you give me a hint ? Thanks.

Comment: What does $a \pm b \pm c = 0$ mean?  For some choice of signs?  For all choices of signs?

Comment: I suppose it means a + b + c = 0 or a - b - c = 0

Comment: @saulspatz there was a question yesterday, very similar and almost certainly from the same source, from a very similar setup you conclude, eventually, that $a^4 + b^4 + c^4 - 2 b^2 c^2 - 2 c^2 a^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 = 0 \; . \; \;$ and this is Heron's formula, four linear factors

Comment: I need to look for that question I guess see what it says

Comment: @questionsaboutmath I can't find it. It was answered, very well, by https://math.stackexchange.com/users/190319/michael-rozenberg?tab=topactivity

Comment: Maybe this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103328

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg that's it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $$a^2+b^2+c^2=\sum_{cyc}(2x^2+xy)=\sum_{cyc}(2x^2+4xy)=2(x+y+z)^2$$ and
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2=\sum_{cyc}(x^2+xy+y^2)(x^2+xz+z^2)=$$
$$=(x+y+z)^4-3(x+y+z)^2(xy+xz+yz)+3(xy+xz+yz)^2=(x+y+z)^4.$$
Id est, $$(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)=\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)=$$
$$=4\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2=4(x+y+z)^4-4(x+y+z)^4=0$$ and we are done!

The cyclic sum works so.

For three variables $a$, $b$ and $c$ we have:
$$\sum_{cyc}a=a+b+c,$$
$$\sum_{cyc}ab=ab+bc+ca,$$
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2b=a^2b+b^2c+c^2a,$$
$$\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2=a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2$$ and something interesting:
$$(a-b)^2(a-c)^2(b-c)^2=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+a^4c^2-2a^3b^3-2a^4bc+2a^3b^2c+2a^3c^2b-2a^2b^2c^2).$$

Comment: Michael, can you find the question you answered yesterday that also ended in Heron's formula? Very similar, I cannot find it. It began with $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 2yz-2zx-2xy=0.$ The relationship was then $bz+cy=cx+az=ay+bx,$ exact same conclusion

Comment: Maybe this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098798

Comment: This might be a silly question but how to read that sigma notation? I haven’t seen it written like that before.

Comment: @questions about math I added something. See now.

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot.